# AJAXing radio buttons created by tableselect form api element

Tags: ajax, theming

I am trying to AJAX a set of radios in a table to load/re-load a couple of additional tables when the user clicks the radio button. I am using the #type = tableselect to create the table. It appears the AJAX is firing (I get the throbber) but my callback is not ever being called.

Here is the relevant form code

```
$form['set_report_reports']['reports'] = array(  
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $reports_hdr,
    '#options' => $reports,
    '#empty' => 'No Reports Found',
    '#multiple' => false,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'show_users_per_report',
        'wrapper' => 'replace-me',
    ),
);

$form['set_report_reports']['access_tables'] = array(
    '#id' => 'replace-me',
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
);
$form['set_report_reports']['access_tables']['assigned'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => array(
        'Name',
    ),
    '#options' => $users_with_access,
    '#empty' => t('No Persons with Access'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="access-granted-table"><h2>Persons with Access</h2>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
$form['set_report_reports']['access_tables']['add_selected'] = array(
    '#type' => 'image_button',
    '#value' => t('add'),
    '#src' => drupal_get_path('module', 'fsp_reports') . '/images/up_icon.png',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="set-report-reports-controls">',
);
$form['set_report_reports']['access_tables']['remove_selected'] = array(
    '#type' => 'image_button',
    '#value' => t('remove'),
    '#src' => drupal_get_path('module', 'fsp_reports') . '/images/dn_icon.png',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
$form['set_report_reports']['access_tables']['users'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => array(
        'username' => t('Name'),
    ),
    '#options' => $users_with_no_access,
    '#empty' => t('No Persons Available'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="users-table"><h2>Persons Available for Access</h2>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

And the callback function

```
function show_users_per_report($form, &$form_state) {
    return $form['set_report_reports']['access_tables'];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `$form['set_report_reports']['access_tables'];` to `drupal_render($form['set_report_reports']['access_tables']);`

Comment: I added the rest of the code for the two tables I am trying to replace because, after some further research, it appears that that may be the area that's causing the problems.

Comment: @Chapabu: I will try that and let you know what happens.

Comment: @Chapabu That didn't work. I really don't think the callback is even getting called. Not sure why, though.

Comment: It appears the problem is with the two image buttons. Don't know why but, if I change those to submit everything works. Anyway, I'm probably going to have to go a different direction but it would be nice to know why the image buttons are causing the issue.